# Vamos ser críticos: jan 2015 Autoavaliação do site

Tags: debate, site-evaluation

Todos nós amamos o [Stack Overflow em Português](http://pt.stackoverflow.com), mas há um mundo de pessoas lá fora que precisam de respostas às próprias perguntas e nem mesmo sabem que este site existe. Quando eles chegam do Google, qual será sua primeira impressão? Vamos tentar ver este site pelos olhos de alguém que nunca o visitou antes e verificar como nos comparamos com o restante da 'Rede.

A [fila de análise de autoavaliação do site](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/review/site-eval) é aberta e preenchida com 10 perguntas que foram feitas e respondidas no último trimestre. 
Faça algumas pesquisas no Google para verificar a facilidade de encontrar as respostas e compare as que temos com as informações de outros sites.

No entanto, a classificação das perguntas é apenas uma parte do quebra-cabeças. Você vê um padrão de perguntas que devem estar encerradas mas não estão? Perguntas ou respostas que precisariam de edição? Algo que vai realmente bem? **Publique uma resposta abaixo para compartilhar suas ideias** e discuta essas perguntas e a integridade do site com seus companheiros usuários!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Resultados finais

- [Formatar double com milhar e decimal](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/44957/formatar-double-com-milhar-e-decimal)

**Pontuação líquida: 38** (Excelente: 40, Satisfatória: 19, Precisa de melhorias: 2)

---

- [CompareTo: Comparison method violates its general contract!](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/44035/compareto-comparison-method-violates-its-general-contract)

**Pontuação líquida: 34** (Excelente: 36, Satisfatória: 21, Precisa de melhorias: 2)

---

- [Gerar backup do banco de dados](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/42101/gerar-backup-do-banco-de-dados)

**Pontuação líquida: 23** (Excelente: 30, Satisfatória: 24, Precisa de melhorias: 7)

---

- [Obter a URL anterior com javascript](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/43814/obter-a-url-anterior-com-javascript)

**Pontuação líquida: 23** (Excelente: 28, Satisfatória: 26, Precisa de melhorias: 5)

---

- [Atributos de herdeiros com prototype não aparecem em reflection Javascript](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/41974/atributos-de-herdeiros-com-prototype-n%c3%a3o-aparecem-em-reflection-javascript)

**Pontuação líquida: 20** (Excelente: 25, Satisfatória: 23, Precisa de melhorias: 5)

---

- [Atualização de dados em um modulo com AngularJS](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/44925/atualiza%c3%a7%c3%a3o-de-dados-em-um-modulo-com-angularjs)

**Pontuação líquida: 9** (Excelente: 16, Satisfatória: 31, Precisa de melhorias: 7)

---

- [TextBox e botão dinâmico C# + ASP.NET](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/44952/textbox-e-bot%c3%a3o-din%c3%a2mico-c-asp-net)

**Pontuação líquida: 1** (Excelente: 12, Satisfatória: 27, Precisa de melhorias: 11)

---

- [Criar um Jogo em linguagem c com o MCU 8051 IDE](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/44996/criar-um-jogo-em-linguagem-c-com-o-mcu-8051-ide)

**Pontuação líquida: -9** (Excelente: 5, Satisfatória: 27, Precisa de melhorias: 14)

---

- [Exceção ao buscar no banco SQLite](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/43567/exce%c3%a7%c3%a3o-ao-buscar-no-banco-sqlite)

**Pontuação líquida: -12** (Excelente: 7, Satisfatória: 28, Precisa de melhorias: 19)

---

- [Erro no decode e convert_from do Postgres](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/42128/erro-no-decode-e-convert-from-do-postgres)

**Pontuação líquida: -42** (Excelente: 3, Satisfatória: 7, Precisa de melhorias: 45)

---

Comment: Ok Comunidade, e o que isso nos diz? Sinceramente, não me diz muito.

Comment: Nem a mim @bfavaretto.

Comment: Deve estar bêbado.. esse tal de "comunidade"..

Comment: mais pirado ainda são os 3 que votaram como resposta útil.. rsrsrsss

Comment: @bfavaretto Eu sinalizaria essa resposta, mas Comunidade é moderador. É tão ruim quando Comunidade não ajuda... :P

Comment: @bfavaretto parece que isso realmente não dizia muita coisa: [Shutting down recurring community self-evaluations](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/261601/229289)

Answer (score 6):

Como um usuário comum, sem dúvidas, posso dizer que a rede Stack é a melhor.

Por outro lado, como colaborador, não gosto muito mas está melhorando por ser um ambiente meritocrático.

Em relação ao SO-Pt em específico, não consigo opinar muito sob o ponto de vista de quem apenas busca respostas pois eu particularmente pesquiso em inglês por ter muito mais conteúdo disponível.

Como colaborador, participo muito mais aqui no SO-Pt do que em outros em inglês porque nos sites em inglês é extremamente disputado e complicado de lidar com os participantes. 
Os próprios colaboradores fazem guerra entre si por alguns pontos de reputação... é um ambiente mais selvagem do que humano.. heheeh.. Teria que dedicar 24 horas por dia todos os dias para conseguir algum espaço.. é inviável. Acho que a quantidade de colaboradores está saturada nos sites SO-en.

Aqui no SO-PT, por ser menos cobiçado, ainda temos alguma civilidade.

Resumindo, não tenho do que reclamar. Não é 100% ideal e nunca será mas é 100% melhor do que qualquer outro forum ou sites do gênero.

Parabéns a equipe, colaboradores e a empresa mantenedora do serviço!

**Crítica sobre a política de avaliação de perguntas e respostas**
Uma crítica que tenho, inclusive já publiquei algumas vezes, é a política que "permite" aos usuários darem ponta pé uns nos outros. Acho desnecessário.
Por exemplo, tem lá uma pergunta e vem alguém e responde corretamente, porém, sem toda aquela formatação monstruosa cheia de detalhes e textos imensos copiados de algum outro site.
Ok, nenhum problema em relação a respostas gigantescas, mas o que critico é a "postura selvagem" de chegar chutando quem se dispõe a colaborar com algo simples e objetivo.
A minha sugestão é tornar o modo selvagem off [off]wild behaviour[/off] e, ao invés de chegar já chutando, pedindo para fechar ou negativar uma resposta, a própria pessoa que viu que a resposta poderia ser melhorada, ao invés de preguiçosamente negativar, poderia ter o mínimo de bom senso de ajudar a melhorar a mesma.
Talvez adicionar algum recurso no qual seja possível sinalizar uma resposta para melhorá-la.
Temos recurso para negativar e fechar então por quê não podemos ter recurso "sinalizar para melhorar o contexto" ? 
Creio que assim seria muito mais justo e positivo. Mas claro, não estou dizendo para remover as funções de negativação.

O que acho um pouco complicado nisso é que alguns enxergam isso aqui como uma competição. Quem tem mais pontos fica em evidência, exerce uma imagem maior de influência, como se soubesse mais do que outros.
Muitos dos que possuem alta pontuação demonstram ter uma boa mentalidade e humildade mas outros poucos não.

O sistema de pontuações é ótimo, porém, também dá margens para alguns desenvolverem esse lado da soberba.
Acho que mudando a política para algo mais civilizado, podemos então evitar inclusive esse tipo de discussão e focarmos mais no aprimoramento de outros assuntos.

Estive pensando nisso esses dias e pensando em como publicar uma crítica e "convocar" os prezados membros para uma solução. Pensei num título "O site é de colaboração ou de competição?"

Saliento que não sugiro isso apenas por mim, pois não estou olhando apenas os meus interesses. Vi vários casos similares ao que já reportei aqui e por isso imagino que haja uma demanda relevante. Acho melhor solucionar isso enquanto é pequeno e fácil de resolver do que deixar esse lado "negativo" se desenvolver por anos e anos e acabar virando uma espécie de cultura.

Comment: Eu até concordo que as vezes as perguntas/respostas são negativadas, depois editadas pelo AP/AR e ficam boas e ninguém as desnegativa (não existe a palavra). Se as pessoas mantivessem a atenção nas negas que dão não haveria esse problema. A ferramenta de sinalizar não sei se traria grandes mudanças e/ou vantagens. Abra um pergunta no meta com essa ideia e vamos ver o que acha a comunidade.

Comment: @Papa Charlie.. se for interpretar todo o texto que postei somente pegando um trecho, aí sim, podemos interpretar da forma como comentou. Mas entenda o texto como um todo e não um parte como colocou, que aliás ficou parecendo uma interpretação leviana.

Comment: Concordo com o @JorgeB. sobre o "desnegativar", acho que deveria existir alguma maneira de quem deu *downvote* receber uma notificação em caso de alteração e/ou comentário na resposta (recebi meu primeiro *downvote* hoje... nãaaaaaaaaaaao... KkKkkKk)

Comment: @DanielOmine, não queria fazer um comentário parecer 'leviano', você não entendeu o que escrevi... Está removido em nome da paz :)

Comment: *O site é de colaboração ou de competição?* é uma excelente discussão. Porque um dos fatores que mais faz o site dar certo (atrair colaboradores) é a gamificação, que também gera a competição.

Comment: fmz.. quando tiver um tempo publicarei uma discussão. Ou se alguém também quiser publicar antes, fique a vontade que também posso ajudar no texto conforme disponiblidade de tempo.

Comment: A competição realmente ajuda o *site* em muitas coisas mas atrapalha em outras. Tem muito usuário que fica segurando voto principalmente em respostas que estão competindo com a resposta dele em uma pergunta. Os votos estão aí para serem dados. Não é para ficar segurando. Não é para se preocupar com a reputação dos outros. Cada um tem que se preocupar só com a sua. Um exemplo que mostra como é complicado é a medalha do [espírito esportivo](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/63/sportsmanship), só 8 possuem e dezenas estão aptos a ter. Veja quantos usuários recebem mais votos do que dão:

Comment: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/users?tab=Voters&filter=all Ninguém é obrigado a votar, a retornar para a comunidade os pontos que recebeu mas é triste ver que alguns usuários não gostam de ajudar a classificar o conteúdo da comunidade. Falta voto. Claro que não é para votar em qualquer coisa, o voto deve ser pensado, o conteúdo deve merecer mas ele precisa ser dado para fazer a comunidade se beneficiar de uma informação de relevância.

Answer (score 6):

> No entanto, a classificação das perguntas é apenas uma parte do
>   quebra-cabeças. Você vê um padrão de perguntas que devem estar
>   encerradas mas não estão? Perguntas ou respostas que precisariam de
>   edição? Algo que vai realmente bem? Publique uma resposta abaixo para
>   compartilhar suas ideias e discuta essas perguntas e a integridade do
>   site com seus companheiros usuários!

Sim, já tomei inclusive uma advertência por responder algo que não devia, pois é irritante a quantidade de perguntas mal feitas sem nem a dimensão do escopo, a pergunta acumula comentários e ninguém responde porque é impossível, não existe o mínimo de informação. As perguntas aqui tem que ser desassociadas do medo de ser ridicularizado e os usuários colocarem todas as informações relevantes, muitas perguntas são feitas pedindo ajuda com APENAS as informações que o perguntador acha relevante, mesmo que resolvamos o problema dele, nenhum conhecimento de qualidade será gerado para leitores alheios.

Ex de algo que o moderador comentou sabendo que é incompleto e não moderou: [Erro ao converter BigInt para inteiro utilizando lambda](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/50103/erro-ao-converter-bigint-para-inteiro-utilizando-lambda)

Esse tipo de pergunta só vai conseguir atrair usuários para serem punidos, principalmente os com rep menor que 50. **Se o usuário que quer ajuda não consegue ler a regra para formular uma pergunta corretamente, deve ser moderado com o mesmo rigor de quem responde desrespeitando as regras**.

Outro exemplo mais fresco: [Como deletar dados de uma tabela relacionada com outra](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/50159/como-deletar-dados-de-uma-tabela-relacionada-com-outra)

Que tipo de conhecimento essa pergunta trará para alguém vindo do google? Precisa ser mago para responder a isso, nem os modelos são postados. Vai virar pergunta de aventureiro tentando acertar o porque por ponto, o que no SO é considerado "resposta de baixa qualidade". Esse usuário em questão está postando 200 perguntas seguidas, todas fragmentadas e sem qualidade para serem respondidas a altura.

Por exemplo, alguém respondeu, "Delete cascade", cara isso depende do banco aceitar o comando, o EF não garante cascade, e por aí vai ...

Entendeu? Vira puro amadorismo responder, gera zero conhecimento e denigre o site com pessoas que ganham rank respondendo com bola de cristal.

Comment: Eu concordo com muita coisa do que você disse. Quanto a eu "moderar" ou não determinado post, tenho meus motivos. Na maioria das vezes é porque o primeiro passo deve ser da própria comunidade, e não dos moderadores. Outras vezes, eu não sei o suficiente do assunto para poder julgar, e preciso me informar antes.

Answer (score 5):

Na generalidade das perguntas que me apareceram, eram as primeiras nas minhas pesquisas e tinham uma qualidade muito boa, com várias respostas interessantes. Mas vi uma ou duas que não me apareciam sequer na primeira página do google, mesmo com a pesquisa pelo título exato. Devo depreender que esse título estaria demasia genérico? Vou colocar a pergunta para verem:

[Obter a URL anterior com javascript](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/43814/obter-a-url-anterior-com-javascript)

Acho que é um dos temas que tem surgido ultimamente por aqui, a edição dos títulos para especificar melhor o problema. Mas até que ponto editar? Até que ponto alterar para parecer mais especifico e de fácil leitura?

Comment: Sério? Com o título exato = [1° lugar](https://www.google.com.br/#q=Obter+a+URL+anterior+com+javascript); Com as palavras "url anterior com/em javascript" = [2° lugar](https://www.google.com.br/#q=url+anterior+com+javascript); Com as palavras "obter url anterior" = [5° lugar](https://www.google.com.br/#q=obter+url+anterior)... Qual seria um bom título para essa questão? Votei como "Excelente"!

Comment: Agora já me aparece em 1º, mas da primeira vez nem sequer havia referência ao SOpt.

Comment: As que considerei como "Precisa melhorar" foram: [essa](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/44035/18327), [essa](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/43567/18327) e [essa](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/42101/18327).

Comment: Este tipo de avaliação é tosco. O que um procura não necessariamente entrega o mesmo resultado para todas as pessoas.

Comment: Sem duvida, mas creio que seja por isso que é feita a avaliação com várias pessoas, para fazer uma média e ter uma noção dos resultados nas buscas =]

Comment: Meu Google está configurado para Inglês. Nesse caso, boa parte das perguntas não ficaram na primeira página (geralmente as perguntas com mais conteúdo se classificaram melhor; algo que fere um pouco a regra "twitter" que coloca perguntas mais sucintas nas primeiras posições quando setamos a linguagem para Português). Interessante.

Answer (score 0):

Sou novo aqui no SO e me deparei com uma situação desagradável. Alguns membros tem como habito responder a pergunta, criticando a pergunta em si e sem dar uma resposta válida, tudo para obter alguns pontos. Tal comportamento desabona o site que já se mostrou ser a melhor fonte de consultas especializadas.

Acredito que a criação de uma funcionalidade onde o criador da pergunta pudesse enviar a resposta que ele considere depreciativa para avaliação pelos membros da comunidade poderia coibir esse comportamento. O criador da pergunta enviaria para avaliação a resposta que ele julgou depreciativa, por um período de 3 horas qualquer  membro (menos todos os envolvidos na pergunta) poderiam avaliar se são a favor ou contra o comportamento apresentado na resposta, o veredicto seria determinado pelos 11 membros de maior pontuação que avaliaram a resposta.

Comment: Como não sei exatamente como foi essa situação sugiro que você crie uma pergunta no Meta com a tag [meta-tag:suporte], descrevendo seu problema, colocando o link para a sua pergunta e explicando o que te incomoda, assim poderemos instruir o que pode ser feito no seu caso.

Comment: Você sempre pode sinalizar qualquer pergunta ou resposta, explicando o motivo, e os moderadores irão analisar a situação.

Answer (score 0):

A resposta de Daniel Ormine e interessante. Também a resposta de Benjamin. Se vc procura um pouco, vc vai achar vários artigos tipo "Why I no longer contribute to StackOverflow". De verdade, precisa entender o objetivo: SO tem como objetivo ter um monte de pessoas para ganhar dinheiro. Tem várias opções para isso e não vamos detalhar, mas SO não e o "Bom Samaritana" do Web (de verdade, no Web, não tem Bom Samaritana)

Além disso, vamos observar o sistema: uma pessoa faz uma pergunta. Isso vai colocar dados na BDD de SO. Legal. Esta pergunta é, por exemplo "Tenho um CSS com erro". 
A partir disso, temos 2 opções:

1) Responder dizendo "Para avaliar o CSS, usa a ferramenta do W3C" e dar o URL desta ferramenta. Assim, a pessoa vai poder resolver o seu problema e vai também poder resolver quase-todos mesmos problemas que ela pode ter com CSS. E outros membros, usando a ferramenta, vão também resolver os problemas de CSS. Eu fiz uma vez este tipo de resposta. Eu recebe um voto negativo. Por que? Veja a segunda opção para entender.

2) Responder especificamente. Tipo "Linha 2 precisa um ; a mais". Este tipo de resposta vai receber voto positivo. Mas ele vai resolver nada. Porque 2 dias depois, vamos ter a mesma pergunta, esta vez com um problema linha 4, depois linha 5 e assim pode diante.

O problema e que a resposta tipo 1 vai dar UMA pergunta, UMA resposta e.... fim do jogo! O que não e interessante para o sistema de SO. De outro lado, a resposta 2 vai resolver o problema em curto prazo. Mas ela é perfeitamente no espírito de SO: curto prazo para obrigar vc a voltar, para fazer 10.000 vezes o mesmo tipo de pergunta.

O que falta se chama um fórum. Para discutir, trocar ideia. Não para resolver o problema da linha 5 de um CSS. E a resposta na pergunta "O site é de colaboração ou de competição?" e fácil fazer: o site é de competição por caso do seu modelo econômico.

O modelo: http://careers.stackoverflow.com/products/candidate-search#pricing

Comment: Não vejo problema nenhum em postar a solução e logo em seguida o link com a ferramenta que pode ajudar o AP futuramente! Sobre o dinheiro, existe aquela frase "de graça só injeção na testa", eu pelo menos considero aqui uma forma de troca de conhecimento =)

Comment: São de acordo com o fato que não deve ter problema. Mas o resultado foi de receber um voto negativo... Sobre a troca de conhecimento, o blog de vc e mas perto disso que o SO. Eu continuo a pensar que um forum da resultados melhores. Eu comecei a programar em 1987 e e já tivemos fórums de discussão sobre "ASM" com resultado bem melhor. Além disso, temos pessoas com grandes reputações que fazem perguntas de iniciantes ... Estranho... A pergunta e saber se tem pessoas interessadas em criar um fórum de programação. O se todo mundo acha SO muito legal. Mas as respostas parecem mostrar que não.